# Request focus on error with Jetpack Compose (with multiple errors)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, focus

I am using Jetpack Compose. I have a form with multiple fields.
When user clicks on the Submit button, my viewModel is triggered and checks each field. In case I have any wrong inputs or missing fields or anything related to form validation, I display a message below each of them.

I would like to request focus only on the first wrong field.
How would you do it?

Comment: Could you show your implementation in your viewmodel ? when user submit a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use focus requester.

Premade composable, that have input parameter called focused, as an example and if (focused==true) call accurate modifier ( .focusRequester() ) and focusrequester.requestfocus() method inside that Composable.

You can then simply call this function to render and focus item by array of elements of form that were validated.
And focus first invalid field.

Note:
Do not forget to put parameter if you use this function in lazy list and with remember call for focusrequester, as recomposition will fail in focus request exception when item changed and focus requester remain.